# HTC one m7 serious problem

Tags: htc-one

Hi all I want you to help me with my htc one m7 international sense 6 android 4.4.3 version of the image 6.15.599.101
  S-ON HR
Tampered UNLOCKED
 I actually rooter phone and I have TWRP Version 2.6.3.0 I wanted to install HTC One HD 50.0.0.zip Maximus and firmware unsigned_7.15.401.1, my problem lies in the installation unsigned firmware file here are the errors that appear:
Skipping check MD5: MD5 no file found
Error flashing zip '/ sdcard / firmware_unsigned ...
Then when I install the ROM htc one Maximus everything goes well in the end we wonder REBOOT SYSTEM NOW when I say YES turns off the phone and comes back in the recovery menu
I download HTC One Maximus 53.0.0.zip when I try to copy by ADB sideload the control file says CAN NOT READ sideload, I also download Sprint_HTC_One_m7wls_1.29.651.10_RUU when I try to install it at the is terminated me wrong signature
I REALLY AM TROUBLE HELP ME PLEASE THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Have you tried disabling verification in recovery? It may let you install it then :)

Comment: Don't use adb sideload...instead I use the following method ;

Answer (score 0):

Don't use adb sideload...instead, I use the following method ;

1. Open recovery (latest version of twrp recommended) but do not enter fastboot mode, stay  in main recovery screen
2. run cmd and enter the following codes under fastboot folder > `adb push rom.zip /data/media/0`   with this code we copy rom.zip into main folder in phone storage.

!!! You can rename your ROM.zip whatever you want, but in this case you should use its new name in command.

3. Flash your rom.zip by using your recovery